# How to add gestures in an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to add gestures to my iPhone. I want a functionality like a user can add a gesture like draw an alphabet say for example 'f' and bind an application like facebook to it. Then, the next time user draws f facebook is opened automatically.

Comment: Is it for jailbreaked iPhone?
If not, you should "trace" it and recognize it, like a OCR.

Comment: no it is not a jailbroken iphone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for custom gesture recognizers base on a predefined path.

That's what Chris Miles did with `CMUnistrokeGestureRecognizer`.

1. you define a custom `UIBezierPath`
2. associate it to the `CMUnistrokeGestureRecognizer`
3. it uses the different gesture recognizer's delegate methods

It's described on [Chris' blog](http://blog.chrismiles.info/2012/12/introducing-cmunistrokegesturerecognizer.html) and available on [Github](https://github.com/chrismiles/CMUnistrokeGestureRecognizer).

To detect multistroke gestures, you could chain multiple unistroke gesture recognizers, requiring all of them to succeed in a given order and with a maximum amount of time between each stroke.

Opening the Facebook app when the complete gesture is detected is as simple as calling

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://"]]
```

Comment: thanks a ton Jilouc. Now, can you help me out for how to open facebook app on drawing f gesture.etc

Comment: I also want to add multistroke gestures like unistroke gestures

Comment: @KaushikAjmera Just edited the answer to give you a starting point for multistroke gestures. Might be a good idea to ask how to chain multiple gesture recognizers in a new question.

Comment: thanx for your answer but can you give me some code stuff for multi stroke gestures